# R Scripts in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-3

It seems the Processing options in QGIS 3.0 no longer include R Scripts (they are not listed as available along with SAGA, GRASS, and GDAL). Is this a change in this version of QGIS or have I had a problem with installation?

Answer (score 4):

As [commented by @ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273623/r-scripts-in-qgis-3-0/281144?noredirect=1#comment436188_273623):

> Actually it's not broken - they were removed from the master install,
>   and are waiting for someone to step up and maintain them as a plugin.
>   ... The situation won't change with 3.0.1/3.2 until
>   someone steps up.

Comment: Is this still the case? Is there a place (like an issue on QGIS's Github, or similar) where visitors of this StackExchange page could look to know when this is coming, or if someone started work on this (possibly to help by testing) ?

Comment: @Mayeul I have no idea.  If you commented on the question and pinged ndawson he may be able to assist.

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 3, the R processing provider is not included in core, but
the `Processing R Provider` plugin is now available (for QGIS 3.4 and later): https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_r/.  You can enable it in QGIS 3 with the plugin manager (*Plugins-> Manage and Install Plugins...*).

The current version is 1.0.1. I had an experimental version installed, and 1.0.1 was not recognized as an update, so I had to uninstall the experimental version to be able to install 1.0.1.

### Edit

**Good news:** Version 0.9.0 of the *Resource Sharing* plugin (http://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/) was made available on http://plugins.qgis.org today, 15 February 2020 (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing), and it includes support for R script collections. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341008/22646 for more details, and for information about available collections and repositories.