# Missing R scripts in QGIS 3 after install

Tags: r, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

After install Processing R Provider plugin (v.1.0.1) in QGIS 3.4 I only got test.rsx. I'm able to create new scritps but I can't acess scripts already installed in my OS (Linux Mint 19.1) trough R repository or download it (like previous version).

Should I change some configuration in QGIS or OS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Found this post https://github.com/north-road/qgis-processing-r/issues/17#issuecomment-459259070. Maybe it's answered.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to point QGIS 3.4 R Scripts in the direction of my QGIS 2 scripts (/Users/MYNAME/.qgis2/processing/rscripts) and they work. I have not figured out how to get new scripts in QGIS 3 yet similar to "Get R scripts from on-line scripts collection" as I was able to in 2.18. For the moment, I am just downloading the scripts in 2.18 and then opening up 3.4 and they are there.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

The nice **Get R scripts from on-line scripts collection** mechanism of QGIS 2 was discontinued when R support in QGIS was moved to the *Processing R Provider* plugin.

The reason for this was that the *Resource sharing* mechanism, provided by the *QGIS Resource Sharing* plugin should be used for all kinds of sharable resources, including R scripts.
But R script support was not included in the *Resource Sharing* plugin from the start, meaning that it became rather inconvenient to add example R scripts to the Processing toolbox.

With version 0.9.0 of the *Resource Sharing* plugin, made available on plugins.qgis.org today, this has changed (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing/). To add the QGIS online R scripts collection you can now:

1. Install the plugin, using the plugin manager.
2. Start it (from *Plugins-> Resource Sharing-> Resource Sharing*).
3. Go to *Settings* and click on the *Reload Repositories* button.
4. Go to *All* and select **QGIS R script collection**.
5. Click on the *Install* button.

If you have *R* and the *Processing R Provider* plugin installed and configured properly, scripts from the original QGIS 2 R script online collection should be available under R in the processing toolbox now.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348772/22646 contains a screenshot of the Processing toolbox with these scripts installed.

Since QGIS R support now relies on the *sf* package for input and output, only the QGIS 2 R scripts that do not rely on spatial input / output will work "out of the box". It is reasonably easy to also make the spatial ones work, and I hope to include more scripts from the QGIS 2 collection soon.

I have done some porting already, and you can get some working examples through the *Resource Sharing* plugin by adding the repository *https://github.com/havatv/QGIS-Resources.git*, reloading repositories and installing *QGIS R script collection*.

### Original answer

The R scripts used in QGIS 2 also work with the Processing R Provider plugin in QGIS 3 (since 3.4).
Some of the scripts have now been

If you would like to use QGIS R scripts from the collection and don't have it in a .qgis2 folder, you can find the collection on

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/rscripts (archived repository)

Just download the rsx file and place it into your rscripts folder
(~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rscripts on Ubuntu). It will then become available in the Processing Toolbox.