# Using R-scripts in QGIS 3.4

Tags: r, qgis-3

I installed the Plugin, and activated R in the provider options.
When I go to the processing toolbox R is available, but I don't have the use online R-scripts, which are mentioned in the documentation.

My script folder is empty as well.

How can I enable the use of the online R-scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading R scripts from the online collection does not seem to be supported in QGIS 3.4 with the `Processing R Provider` plugin. But you can find the collection on

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/rscripts (archived repository)

You can download the rsx files you need and place them in your rscripts folder (~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rscripts on Ubuntu). They should then become available in the Processing Toolbox.

### Update:

The `QGIS Resource Sharing` plugin is supposed to support sharing of resource collections in QGIS, and we can use it to also share R scripts.

I have been doing some testing, and have created a repository with the on-line collection of QGIS 2 R scripts. Use the URL: `https://github.com/havatv/qgis_rscripts.git` to test it with the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin.
Since there is currently no mechanism in the plugin to automatically make content from rscript repositories available in Processing, you have to manually set the R script folder to something like:

`/home/<username>/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/resource_sharing/repositories/github.com/havatv/qgis_rscripts/collections/R-scripts-QGIS2/processing/rscriptsqgis2` (on Ubuntu).

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\resource_sharing\repositories\github.com\havatv\qgis_rscripts\collections\R-scripts-QGIS2\processing\rscriptsqgis2` (on Windows)

### Update 2:

The QGIS 2 online R script collection have now been added to the official QGIS Resources Sharing Repository (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Resources), so it is better to use that one. The collection is called **QGIS R script collection** (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Resources/tree/master/collections/qgis_rscripts).

I have also an open pull request (https://github.com/akbargumbira/qgis_resources_sharing/pull/62) on the *QGIS Resource Sharing* plugin that hopefully will fix R script support. Once that is merged, and a new version of the plugin is released, the R scripts from the QGIS 2 online collection can be conveniently installed using the QGIS rscripts directory, and will immediately be available in the *Processing Toolbox*.

### Update 3:

Version 0.9.0 of the Resource Sharing plugin was made available on http://plugins.qgis.org today (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing), and the good news is that it includes support for R script collections. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341008/22646 for more details, and for information about available collections and repositories.