# QGIS enabling R via plugin

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins, spatstat

System Ubuntu 19.10, QGIS 3.4

I am trying to utilise R in QGIS for Ripley's K function.

The sample R script 'Scatterplot' works with the Processing R Provider plugin, which indicates r-base is installed OK.  However, I have installed the Spatstat package and the various categories do not appear in the QGIS Processing Toolbox.

I am guessing the R scripts folder needs setting?  If so, what would I need to direct the plugin to?

Comment: In addition to R folder, I set `User Library Folder` to where I have R packages.  I am using Processing R Provider in QGIS 3.8.3 on windows, so it may be different situation.

Comment: confirmed with QGIS 3.4.12.

Answer (score 2):

This is my settings.

1. The location R is installed.
2. R scripts folder is accessed from `Menu > Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder`.
3. User library folder is where I have R packages.

[image]

Then, RSX script for Ripley's K:

[image]

```
##Kazuhito Vector Analysis=group
##Layer=vector point
##showplots
library("maptools")
library("spatstat")
points=as.ppp(Layer)
K=Kest(points)
plot(K)
```

It gives me this html output (via Results Viewer panel):

[image]

File system would be different from yours, but hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kazuhito,  Sorry for not responding sooner.  The file structure is different in Linux, but I'm trying to find the equivalents.  However, I can use the r scripts so it does not matter too much.  Thanks for your demo. Neil

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Version 0.9.0 of the *Resource Sharing* plugin was made available on http://plugins.qgis.org today (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing), and the good news is that it includes support for R script collections.
See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341008/22646 for more details, and for information about available collections and repositories.

The *QGIS Official Repository* now also includes a collection with R scripts. The name of the collection is *QGIS R script collection*.

### Original answer

(modified according to recent developments in the official QGIS repository)

It is currently not possible to "import" R scripts from the on-line collection (as could be done in QGIS 2), but it is possible to download the scripts and add them "manually". See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341008/22646.

The "QGIS Resource Sharing" plugin supports import of R script collections.
I have done some testing by creating a resource for the plugin that contains these QGIS 2 R scripts.

Using the following steps, I was able to get this to work in QGIS 3.10.1 (I suppose it should work also with QGIS 3.4).

1. Add the "QGIS Resource Sharing" plugin
2. Open it (Plugins-> Resource Sharing-> Resource Sharing)
3. Choose the *Settings* tab
4. Click *Reload repositories*
5. Choose the *All* tab
6. Select `QGIS R script collection` in the list to install R scripts that work in QGIS 3 with Processing R provider 2 (select `QGIS R script collection (from QGIS 2)` if you want the original QGIS 2 collection - many of these scripts need to be modified to work), click on the
   *Install* button
7. The collection should now be listed in the *Install* tab
8. *Close* the plugin

With recent versions (>= 0.9.0) of the *QGIS Resource Sharing* plugin the R scripts should now be available under various groups under R in the processing toolbar (see illustration below).

With older versions (< 0.9.0) of the plugin, you also have to:

9. Open the Processing settings (*Settings-> Options-> Processing tab*)
10. Go to *Providers-> R-> R scripts folder*
11. On Ubuntu, set the path to (or include in the path):

    `/home/<user>/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/resource_sharing/repositories/github.com/havatv/qgis_rscripts/collections/R-scripts-QGIS2/processing/rscriptsqgis2`

    On Windows, set the path to:

    `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\resource_sharing\repositories\github.com\havatv\qgis_rscripts\collections\R-scripts-QGIS2\processing\rscriptsqgis2`

    It is possible to provide several directories here, separated
    by a semicolon (";").
12. All the R scrips from the QGIS 2 on-line collection should
    now be available in the Processing Toolbox (only some of
    the groups are expanded in the screenshot below):

    [image: Processing toolbox with some R scripts shown]

    The scripts at the top come from the default rscripts folder -
    it is included in my `R scripts folder` path.